# Loading OBJ file in three.js

Tags: three.js

I was trying to visualize a simple 3D model of the cylinder on the browser by importing OBJ file in  three.js. I started with running simple example of three.js's OBJ loader:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html

which works fine locally.

I tried just by replacing the path of OBJ file with that of mine, but it failed to load. I double check the Path and it is correct.

On checking errors on the console on Firefox `(Crtl + Shift + k)`, it says: `Syntax Error` and throws following error:

> [22:59:30.865] Error: WebGL: DrawElements: bound vertex attribute buffers do not have sufficient size for given indices from the bound element array @ http://localhost/~harmanpreet/three.js/build/three.min.js:455

The OBJ file is converted from model made in BRL-CAD (.g to .obj conversion). Link to OBJ file: http://devplace.in/~harman/cyl1_bot_dump.obj

Can anybody figure out what is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Your .obj loads for me with three.js v56.  Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using revision: 59. Now it is working after I simplified the above example of threejs OBJ loader. I just kept only code block relevant obj file loading so get into the problem and somehow it worked. 

Earlier, I was trying to just replace path of OBJ file in example with that of mine and it didn't worked.

Comment: Hi harman052, the link to the OBJ file is dead. Did you find a solution, or can you provide additional information.

Comment: This problem was solved. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @harman052 Would you please tell How did you solve this problem ?  I am using three.js r74, but still encountered this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your .obj file looks correct according to specs, but I would advise you to use a non-minified three.js version and then look at the code surrounding the error message.

Also what you could try is replacing the "g" in the obj file at start with an "o" (g = group, o = object) - I'm not sure how three.js handles this internally or if it makes a difference, but I guess it won't hurt to try.

Other than that the error seems to be saying something like "I encountered an array index which is out of bounds", meaning a face (f in the .obj file) uses an index which is higher than the highest defined index, but that doesn't seem to be the case with your file (.obj indexes start at 1, so everything should be fine).

Comment: No change after changing from "g" to "o" in OBJ file, and from three.min.js to three.js in html file. :(

Comment: There should be no change if you change from minified to non minified - but you'll be able to inspect what three.js is doing in it's sourcecode easily if you use the non-minified version (there is no magic, it's just plain javascript). At that point you can probably also look at the stack trace you should be getting in your console to see where the error originates from.